# Prove $\{a_n\} = d_1\cdot2^{-1}+d_2\cdot2^{-2}+\dots+d_n\cdot2^{-n}$ converges to a number between 0 and 1

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Let $\{d_n\}$ be a sequence of 0's and 1's and define a sequence of numbers $\{a_n\}$ by $$a_n = d_1\cdot2^{-1}+d_2\cdot2^{-2}+\dots+d_n\cdot2^{-n}.$$
Prove that this sequence converges to a number between 0 and 1.

I've shown that the largest value of $a_n$ occurs when $d_k = 1$ for all $k\le n$ (and that the smallest value occurs when $d_k = 0$ for all $k\le n$). I'm not sure how to show that $\lim a_n \le 1$ when $d_n$ = 1 for all $n$. I know $\{a_n\}$ is non-decreasing. I've tried to use induction, but I quickly hit a wall. I won't type out exactly what I've tried with induction unless needed, just because I have a hunch (possibly erroneously) that induction isn't the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically done already. Your sequence is bounded by 
$$
0 \leq a_n \leq \sum_1^{\infty}2^{-n}=1
$$
You have a monotone, increasing sequence, which is bounded above.Therefore a limit exists. Now you can simply assume the existence of the limit.
For this limit, there holds 
$$
0\leq\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \leq 1
$$
as for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there holds $0 \leq a_n \leq 1$. Taking limits preserves "$\leq$".

Comment: How would you prove $\sum_1^{\infty}2^{-n}=1$? Or that $\sum_1^k 2^{-n}\le 1$, which may be easier. When trying through induction, I get to $a_{n+1} \le 1 + 2^{-n}$, and then don't see how to move on from there.

Comment: It the geometric series, quite well known.